# update the mongodb with updated collections

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a csv file and after parsing that file, I am creating a db in mongodb. I use to get the updated  csv file frequently ( with new records added ). How can I efficiently  update the db ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CSV includes both existing records and new ones, you could:

- Remember the last entry you processed and continue processing from there (assuming the CSV is always in the same order, and you don't need to update existing records)
- Re-process the CSV and `upsert` based on unique field(s) criteria (upsert => insert if the document doesn't exist, otherwise update existing document)

#### MongoDB 2.6: Use the Bulk API

If you are using MongoDB 2.6+, there is a [new Bulk API](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/84922794768/mongodbs-new-bulk-api) that enables more efficient batch operations (so you can do a [Bulk Upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/), for example).

#### Older version of MongoDB: consider the Bulk Insert API

Prior to MongoDB 2.6, there is a more limited [Bulk Insert API](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/core/bulk-inserts/) which you could also consider using if you haven't upgraded yet. The older bulk API only provides for inserts, so for other operations such as update or upsert you would have to send individual commands.